# CSS Safari: Absolute Bottom/Left not working as expected

Tags: html, ios, css, safari

Bug confirmed on: iOS Mac v2015 + iPhone 11: both running **Safari**

Works with: iOS Mac v2015 + Windows 10 + Android: **Chrome** 79.0.93..., **Firefox** 71

I got this https://github.com/frizzant/bulma-graphs (preview: https://frizzant.github.io/bulma-graphs/ ) extension. When the viewport gets below **768px**, the text turns vertical, and is positioned `absolute` so it sticks to the bottom.

This works as expected in Chrome + Firefox, but Safari does its strange magic.
All of the `<p>`'s seem to clog up at the **bottom left**, as if they had the same parent. Any idea what is causing this?

HTML (partial):

```
<div class="graphs-container" data-title="Horizontal Graph">
    <div class="data-container column is-full columns is-mobile is-size-7 has-text-white is-marginless">
        <div data-title="One" data-value="10"><p>One</p></div>
        <div data-title="Two" data-value="50"><p>Two</p></div>
        <div data-title="Three" data-value="100"><p>Three</p></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS: SCSS (partial):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .graphs-container {
    .data-container {

      &:not(.is-vertical-graph) > div {
        p {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: -13px;
          left: 5px;

          -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
          transform: rotate(-90deg);
          -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
          -ms-transform-origin: top left;
          transform-origin: top left;

          text-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #000000;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `.graphs-container .data-container.columns > div` in your Github custom.css

or

in `.data-container.columns > div` in your custom.scss

Printscreen:
[image: Printscreen]

Comment: My hero! Thanks alot!